# Codeigniter 4 проблема с загрузкой файлов

Tags: php, codeigniter

Пишу сайт на codeigniter 4 и при использовании input type file вылазит ошибка на роутер 
в этом месте

```
$newName = $this->file->getRandomName();
```

часть кода

```
$this->file = $this->request->getFile('poster');
$newName = $this->file->getRandomName();
$this->file->move(WRITEPATH.'uploads', $newName);
$this->news->save($this->fieldsTable());
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, для того, чтобы инициализировать библиотеку файлов с учетом файла, который приходит из формы, нужно написать примерно так:

```
    $uploadedFile = $this->request->getFile('file');
    $file = new \CodeIgniter\Files\File($uploadedFile);

    $newName = $file->getRandomName();
    $file->move(WRITEPATH.'uploads', $newName);
```

об этом можно почитать в [документации](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/user_guide_src/source/libraries/files.rst)

Во-вторых, не забывайте о том, что работаете не с релизной версией фреймворка, данном случае, возникает ошибка при перемещении файла из временной директории в директорию назначения. Сама ошибка тут system/Files/File.php:173, достаточно исправить

```
if ( ! @rename($this->getPath(), $destination))
```

на

```
if ( ! @rename($this->getRealPath(), $destination))
```

О разнице этих методов, читайте в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.splfileinfo.php)

Comment: Разобрался с этим, в views забыл вставить enctype="multipart/form-data", а в system/Files/File.php:173 я не манял оно не критично
Подключение File я сделал через наследуемый контролер где описываются все переменные
а в основном контролере
$this->file = $this->request->getFile('poster');
    $newName = $this->file->getRandomName();
    $this->file->move('upload/post/'.date('Y-m-d'), $newName);
    $this->files = '/upload/post/'.date('Y-m-d').'/'.$this->file->getName();